# Random Variable Distribution - Weight of males student is more than twice the weight of a randomly chosen female student

Tags: probability, random-variables

The weights of male students in a college are modeled by a normal distribution with mean 80 kg and standard deviation 7 kg. The weights of female students in the college are modeled by a normal distribution with mean 54 kg and standard deviation 5 kg. Find the probability that the weight of a randomly chosen male student is more than twice the weight of a randomly chosen female student.

---

Use of calculator is permitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

To be found is $P(M-2F>0)$ where $M$ and $F$ are independent random variables, both having normal distribution.

In this situation random variable $M-2F$ also has normal distribution.

You can find its parameters by calculation of mean and variance.

Comment: oh my god! Thank you so much. I just came to realize how dumb it was of me to not bring 2F from the RHS to the LHS. New chapters do be like that. Thanks!

Comment: Because of independency you can take the summation of the variances of $M$ and $-2F$:$$\mathsf{Var}(M-2F)=\mathsf{Var}(M)+4\mathsf{Var}(F)$$